# Mac OS Terminal showing [~] ruby 2.7.1p83 $

Tags: terminal

So I Installed Ruby 2.7.1 on my Mac OS 10.13. Now when I open the terminal window I see this by default.

[image: 1]

It is no longer showing the default path /Users/shivankkapur/ etc

How do I change this?

Comment: This is a bash window, not mac terminal. Both are similar, terminal has more features. You can google the differences.

Comment: Ok how do I exit from bash to terminal?

Comment: First, when you do command+space and type terminal and enter, what opens?
You can just close it, top left

Comment: I put the screenshot in my post. The bash is what opens every time

Comment: Hmm. Goto terminal > preferences and in "general" tab see shell open with. what does that say?

Comment: it says /bin/bash . thanks changed it to /bin/zsh